# Vue TSX - How to tell Typescript that the HTML attributes are allowed in reusable components?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, jsx, tsx

Suppose I have this input component:

```
import { defineComponent } from "@vue/runtime-core"

export default defineComponent({
    inheritAttrs: false,
    setup(props, { attrs }) {
        return () => (
            <div>
                <input type="text" {...attrs} />
            </div>
        )
    }
})
```

Now, I use this component like so and provide `type="password"` attribute:

```
import { defineComponent } from "@vue/runtime-core"
import Input from "./components/input"

export default defineComponent({
    setup(props, { attrs }) {
        return () => <Input type="password"></Input>
    }
})
```

But Typescript complains:

```
Property 'type' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttribute'> & VNodeProps & AllowedComponentProps & ComponentCustomProps>'
```

Answer (score 5):

So I am not a Vue.JS expert (please tell me if it doesn't work and why), but after some research I found out that you have to type the `props` by adding a `props` object to `defineComponent`. That will tell TypeScript that you can pass specific props.

```
import { defineComponent } from "@vue/runtime-core"

export default defineComponent({
    inheritAttrs: false,
    props: {
        type: String // this is the typing (warning: you cannot use typescript types here)
    }
    setup(props, { attrs }) {
        return () => (
            <div>
                <input type={props.type ?? "text"} {...attrs} />
            </div>
        )
    }
})
```

You might ask what the `??` operator does. I like to call it the "defaulting operator" because it default the value before it with the value after it. In this case it means that if `props.type` is `undefined` or `null` it will replace it with `"text"`.